# Error: desplegando mi modal en boostrap

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-3

Tengo un problema al desplegar un **modal bootstrap**.

Mi pagina web esta compuesta por varias secciones y para moverse entre ellas existe un scroll con anclas y un formulario de contactos.

Cuando me dirijo directamente al formulario y presiono el botón enviar no se despliega el modal ya configurado, pero cuando me dirijo a el la seccion donde esta el formulario por medio de mi anclas (configuradas con un scroll en jquery) si se me despliga el modal correctamente.

Asumo que lo que pasa es que al usar el sistema de anchas ya se carga la librery en mi pagina y entonces boostrap ya puede hacer uso de ellas y pro eso de despliega. en cambio cuando voy directamente entonces no se carga bien la libreria.

## `

```
        <head>
            <title>Ing. Adrian Rojas Terraza</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="" href="css/master.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-flex.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="" href="css/profile.css">
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/icon.png" />
            <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="modal.html">

            <script src="lib/js/smooth-scroll.min.js"></script>

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <script src="js/js.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body>
```

**ARTZ**

```
                    <a href="#who"><img src="lib/icons/PNG/user-tie.png"> Perfil profesional</a>
                    <a href="#services"><img src="lib/icons/PNG/terminal.png"> Conocimientos</a>
                    <a href="#herramientas"> <img src="lib/icons/PNG/hammer.png"> Herramientas</a>
                    <a href="#curriculum"><img src="lib/icons/PNG/profile.png"> Curriculum</a>
                    <a href="#local"><img src="lib/icons/PNG/location2.png"> ¡Contactame!</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
                    <div>
                        <img src="img/profile.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                        <div class="ing">ING. Adrian Rojas Terraza </div>
                        <div class="wrap">
                                <div class="widget">
                                <div class="fecha">
                                <p id="diaSemana" class="diaSemana">,</p>
                                <p id="dia" class="dia"></p>
                                <p> de </p>
                                <p id="mes" class="mes"></p>
                                <p> del </p>
                                <p id="year" class="year"></p>


                                </div>

                    <div class="reloj">
                    <p id="horas" class="hora">  </p>
                    <p>:</p>

                    <p id="minutos" class="minutos"></p>

                    <p>:</p>
                    <div class="cajaSegundos">
                    <p id="ampm" class="ampm"></p>
                    <p id="segundos" class="segundos"></p>

                    </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </header>

    <!-- Quien Soy-->



            <Section id='who' class="content who">
                <h2 class="title">Perfil profesional. <span><img src="img/iconospage/PNG/user.png"></span></h2>
                <h3><p>Profesional orientado al logro, con conocimientos adquiridos en el ámbito laboral, dispuesto a formar parte de un equipo de trabajo, colaborando así con la empresa en el logro de sus objetivos, con altos estándares de responsabilidad y compromiso dentro de la organización</p>
                </h3>
                <br>
                <br>

                <div >
                    <span>
                        <img class="logBig" src="img/iconospage/SVG/board.svg">
                    </span>
                </div>
            </Section>


            <!--Servicios-->
            <section id="services" class="content services">
                <h2 class="title">Conocimientos. <span><img src="img/iconospage/PNG/lamp.png"></span></h2>
                <p>Lenguajes de programacion y estandar de programacion web.</p>
            <br>
                <div href="www.google.com" class= 'listas'><a href="http://google.com" ><img data-toggle="tooltip" title="Html5!" class= 'listaImg' src="img/html5.png"></a> </div>
                <div href="#" class= 'listas'><a href="http://www.javascript.com/"><img data-toggle="tooltip" title="Javascript!" class= 'listaImg' src="img/Javascript.png"></div></a>
                <div  href="#" class= 'listas'><a href="http://php.net/"><img   data-toggle="tooltip" title="php!" class= 'listaImg' src="img/php.png"></div>
                <div href="#" class= 'listas'><a href=""><img  data-toggle="tooltip" title="css!" class= 'listaImg' src="img/css.svg"></div>
                <div  href="#" class= 'listas'><a href="http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/articles/sql/index.html"><img  data-toggle="tooltip" title="plsql!" class= 'listaImg' src="img/plsql.png"></a></div>
                <div  href="#" class= 'listas'><a href="http://jquery.com"><img  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Jquery!" class= 'listaImg' src="img/jquery.gif"></a></div>


            </section>

    <!-- TARIFAS-->
            <section id="herramientas" class="content services" style=' background: #161123'>
                <h2 class="title"> Herramientas de Gestion.  <span><img src="img/iconospage/PNG/settings.png"></span></h2>
                <p>
                    Herramientas y programas, en el manejo de la gestion diaria de actividades.
                </p>
                <br>
            <div class= 'listas'><a href="http://es.atlassian.com/software/jira"><img data-toggle="tooltip" title="Jira!" class= 'listaImg' src="img/jira.png"> </div></a>
                <div class= 'listas'><a href="http://bmc.com/it-solutions/remedy-itsm.html"><img data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remedy!" class= 'listaImg' src="img/remedy.png"></div></a>
        <div class= 'listas'><a href="http://www.quest.com/mx-es/toad/"><img  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Toad!" class= 'listaImg' src="img/toad.png"></div></a>
        <div class= 'listas'><a href="http://trello.com"><img data-toggle="tooltip" title="Trello!" class= 'listaImg' src="img/trello.png"></div></a>
        <div class= 'listas'><a href="http://zapier.com"><img data-toggle="tooltip" title="Zapier!" class= 'listaImg' src="img/zapier.png"></div></a>
        <div class= 'listas'><a href="http://zapier.com"><img data-toggle="tooltip" title="Git!" class= 'listaImg' src="img/git.png"></div></a>
        <div class= 'listas'><a href="http://zapier.com"><img data-toggle="tooltip" title="Slack!" class= 'listaImg' src="img/Slack.png"></div></a>
        <div class= 'listas'><a href="http://zapier.com"><img data-toggle="tooltip" title="Zapier!" class= 'listaImg' src="img/gsuite.png"></div></a>
        <div class= 'listas'><a href="http://zapier.com"><img data-toggle="tooltip" title="Sublime!" class= 'listaImg' src="img/sublime.png"></div></a>
        <div class= 'listas'><a href="http://zapier.com"><img data-toggle="tooltip" title="Office!" class= 'listaImg' src="img/office.svg"></div></a>
        <div class= 'listas'><a href="http://zapier.com"><img data-toggle="tooltip" title="Office!" class= 'listaImg' src="img/windows.png"></div></a>



    </section>
    <!--CURRICULUM-->
    <section id="curriculum" class="content tarifas">
        <article class="contain">
            <h2 class="title" >Curriculum <span><img src="img/iconospage/PNG/board.png"></span></h2>
            <p>En rasgos generales</p>
            <p>
                <li>Analista Senior QA, Consis international</li>
                <li>Analista de Sistemas, CANTV</li>
                <li>Analista desarrollador, Cooperativa ITESI.COM</li>
            </p>
            <p>Para acceder a la informacion completa de mi hoja de vida Click a el Boton <b>Descargar</b></p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Descargar</a>
        </article>
    </section>

    <!--LOCALIZACION-->

    <section id="local" class="content local">
        <h2 class="title">Contactame! <span><img src="img/iconospageblack/PNG/envelope.png"></span></h2>
        <p><h4>Para hacer efectiva nuestra comunicacion, ingresa tus datos en el formulario y pongamonos en contacto!!</h4></p>
        <br>
        <div class="formMaster">

            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Tipo de persona (Natural ó Juridica)</label>
                    <select class="form-control">

                        <option>Natural.</option>
                        <option>Juridica.</option>

                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <label  for="exampleInputEmail1">Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre.">

                    <br>
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Numero de Contacto.</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text input">
                    <br>
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                    <br>

                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Descripción</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>



                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Enviar</button>
            </form>
              <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
             <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">¡Gracias por contactarme!  <?php echo 'HOOOOOLA';?></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <p><b>El Mensaje </b> fue enviado con <b>exito</b>, pronto me pondre en contacto con usted.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>
             </div>

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>

            <figure class="map">
                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3923.2075114183667!2d-66.83153459579866!3d10.484301494803542!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xc52d4083f54e7f4f!2sConsis+Internacional!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sve!4v1521669013885" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </figure>
        </div>

    </section>
    <section class="footer">
        <div class="version">Sha-6514756sdf5g47sd5</div>
        <div class="Autor">© 2018 - Pagina diseñada y creada por<b> Ing. Adrian Rojas Terraza. </b></div>
        <div class="redes">
        <img clas='imgHome' src='img/icomoonredes/SVG/instagram.svg' >
        <img clas='imgHome' src='img/icomoonredes/SVG/facebook.svg' >
        <img clas='imgHome' src='img/icomoonredes/SVG/linkedin.svg' >   
        </img></div>
    </section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <div class="loader-page"> </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/reloj.js"  >  </script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Agrega el código de tu pagina para que se pueda entender mejor  el  error que puede estar sucediendo.

Comment: listo amigo, recalco que estoy en proceso de aprendizaje y obviamente estoy aprendiendo las mejores practicas

Comment: A mi parecer deberias separar crear un archivo llamado base.html el cual contendra todos tus `css` `js`, necesarios para cargar `bootstrap` y tus paginas simplemente heredan esta plantilla(base.html)..
para una mejor organizacion. [herencia plantilla](https://borrowbits.com/2013/11/herencia-facil-de-plantillas-en-php-y-sin-volver-al-paleolitico/) Otro punto seria para invocar a tu ventana modal tienes dos vias por un boton como indica la documentacion oficial o a su vez mediante `javascript`. Asegurate que todas tus librerias cargen `bootstrap` tus `css` `js` y que el llamado sea por boton o j

Comment: oko muchas gracias, tratare de dividir el código para organizarme mejor como me indicas pero por ahora estoy enfocado en resolver el inconveniente.